# 1Password "Clipboard Contents Restored" notification

Tags: macos, notifications, copy-paste

When using 1Password for macOS, the following Notification Center notification frequently and annoyingly pops up in the corner of my screen:

[image: Clipboard Contents Restored]

> Clipboard Contents Restored
> Prior clipboard restored

That's a useful feature, but I never want to be notified of it.

How can I prevent that notification in 1Password? Is there a way to turn off that notification without disabling all 1Password notifications?

Answer (score 1):

I have only seen that popup when copying a one-time password. That notification you can disable.

Go to the 1password preferences, open tab 'Notifications' and untick the 'one-time passwords' box.
[image: 1password notifications tab]